# Database interrogation and echo from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, html-table

I have 2 tables in my DB.
First is called birou and has:

> id name desk (3 columns)

The second one is called flux_receptie and has:

> id motiv nume_client reg_date status_solutionare status_preluare
>    ora_preluare ora_rezolvare operator_preluare operator_solutionare (10 columns)

1. -desk- column is the desk where an user works. He selects on which desk he is working in each day from his account. (This mean I use sessions).
2. -operator_preluare- is the user account.
3. -nume_client- is the name of the client which comes in the office (he introduces his name personally in the database through an input page php).

I need an echo which has to show: the client ID, nume_client and the desk value (assigned by the user to itself).

My code so far is working but I need to add desk value from the birou:

```
$rst=mysql_query("select * from flux_receptie where status_preluare ='PRELUAT' order by ora_preluare desc limit 3",$link);
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($rst)) 
        if(($res)==TRUE)
         echo "<br /><center>
<table border='1' class='fixed'>
<td><center>$res[0]</center></td><br /><br /><br /><br />
<td><center>$res[2]</center></td><br /><br /><br /><br />
<td><center>&#10148;    BIROUL **VALUE DESK HERE**</center></td>
</center>";
?>
```

I hope you understood what I am trying to say here. I need to combine the 2 tables in order to show 3 simple values (2 Already are shown, but I need the desk value).

Can anyone please help me? I Googled but I did not really understood how to combine them.

Comment: You use a join, what field are the two tables related on?

Comment: One moment. I will rephrase my question.

Comment: I rephrased my question, thanks.